# Обновить генератор firebird в пределах года

Tags: firebird, interbase

Всем привет.
При создании документа в firebird срабатывает генератор

```
BEGIN
   RESULT = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID,1);
   RESULT_NUM = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_NUM_GET,1);
  suspend;
END
```

Хотелось бы чтобы каждый год 01.01 он обнулялся и начинался с 1.
Примерно так не сработало, ругается на CREATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ZAYAVA_BI_0 FOR ZAYAVA
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (CAST('01.01.'||EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NEW.date) AS DATE) = NEW.date) THEN 
    BEGIN
      SET GENERATOR(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID,0);
      SET GENERATOR(GEN_ZAYAVA_NUM_GET,0);
    END;
  IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID, 1);
  IF (NEW.NUM IS NULL) THEN NEW.NUM = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_NUM_GET,1);
END
```

Comment: Как ругается? Что пишет? Добавьте в вопрос

Comment: SET GENERATOR(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID,0); - в триггере не работает. Надо получить тек. значение генератора в переменную gen1 = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID, 0);  Затем установить снова GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID, -gen1);

Comment: 1. Сбрасывать генератор для ID я оооооочень не рекомендую. Просто не надо так делать.

Comment: 2. Перед сбросом генератора номера стоит сначала убедиться, что это первое срабатывание в году. Во-первых, за 1.01.гггг может быть несколько документов, а во-вторых их может вообще не быть, это же выходной.

Comment: Да согласен, вот как бы сбросить его или как бы вообще начать вести нумерацию?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант реализации (возможно надо подкорректировать):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ZAYAVA_BI_0 FOR ZAYAVA 
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0 
AS
    declare genT int;
BEGIN
    IF (CAST('01.01.'|| cast(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NEW.date) as varchar(10)) AS DATE) = NEW.date) THEN 
    BEGIN
      genT = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID,0);
      GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID, -genT);
      genT = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_NUM_GET,0);
      GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_NUM_GET, -genT);
    END;
    IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_ID, 1);
    IF (NEW.NUM IS NULL) THEN NEW.NUM = GEN_ID(GEN_ZAYAVA_NUM_GET,1); 
END
```

Посмотрите ещё у Вас занята уже позиция триггера номер 0 ?

Comment: Да, кстати вот сейчас заметил что много триггеров на позиции 0, там какое то ограничение есть?

Comment: @Boris, ограничения нет, только общее количество триггеров на таблицу, и оно очень большое. Проблема может быть в том, что вы не можете влиять на порядок срабатывания триггеров с одним номером.

Comment: Не сработал код